# How to identify whether a file is normal file or directory

Tags: python, pathlib

How do you check whether a file is a normal file or a directory using python?

Comment: if you are using the pathlib library do: `p.is_file()` see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44228884/1601580

Answer (score 184):

`os.path.isdir()` and `os.path.isfile()` should give you what you want.  See: 
http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html

Comment: if you are using the pathlib library do: `p.is_file()` see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44228884/1601580

Answer (score 45):

As other answers have said, `os.path.isdir()` and `os.path.isfile()` are what you want.  However, you need to keep in mind that these are not the only two cases.  Use `os.path.islink()` for symlinks for instance.  Furthermore, these all return `False` if the file does not exist, so you'll probably want to check with `os.path.exists()` as well.

Comment: if you are using the pathlib library do: `p.is_file()` see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44228884/1601580

Answer (score 32):

Python 3.4 introduced [the `pathlib` module](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/pathlib.html#) into the standard library, which provides an object oriented approach to handle filesystem paths. The relavant methods would be `.is_file()` and `.is_dir()`:

```
In [1]: from pathlib import Path

In [2]: p = Path('/usr')

In [3]: p.is_file()
Out[3]: False

In [4]: p.is_dir()
Out[4]: True

In [5]: q = p / 'bin' / 'vim'

In [6]: q.is_file()
Out[6]: True

In [7]: q.is_dir()
Out[7]: False
```

Pathlib is also available on Python 2.7 via [the pathlib2 module on PyPi.](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pathlib2/)

Answer (score 8):

```
import os

if os.path.isdir(d):
    print "dir"
else:
    print "file"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
os.path.isdir('string')
os.path.isfile('string')
```

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
import os.path
if os.path.isdir("path/to/your/file"):
    print "it's a directory"
else:
    print "it's a file"
```

Answer (score 3):

To check **if** *a file/directory exists*:

```
os.path.exists(<path>)
```

To check **if** *a path is a directory*:

```
os.path.isdir(<path>)
```

To check **if** *a path is a file*:

```
os.path.isfile(<path>)
```