# how to check if a file is a directory or regular file in python?

Tags: python

How do you check if a path is a directory or file in python?

Comment: if you are using the pathlib library do: `p.is_file()` see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44228884/1601580

Answer (score 700):

```
os.path.isfile("bob.txt") # Does bob.txt exist?  Is it a file, or a directory?
os.path.isdir("bob")
```

Comment: if you are not using absolute paths, like in the example, it would only check for "bob"s existence in the script directory (or where python is currently situated in the filesystem)

Comment: os.path.isfile("1.mp4") gives me false! Why is that?

Comment: that's because you aren't using full path there. use `os.path.isfile("/path/to/1.mp4")`

Comment: What if the file paths don't exist yet? Both functions return False.

Comment: @cs95, You're going to have to check if the file exists first, and then check if it is a directory. If a file doesn't exist, it can't be a directory anyway! You're looking for os.path.exists: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists

Comment: @b4ux1t3 actually i got a case where isfile is False but isdir is True

Comment: @bakalolo Yeah, that's because I wasn't specific enough. isfile checks if something that exists is a file, isdir checks if something that exists is a directory. I specifically pointed out os.path.exists, which returns true if there is _anything_ at the path specified. If you check if the path exists at all, you can then check if it is specifically a directory. If a path exists and it is not a directory, it is a file. In any case, you can check if something exists and what it is in exactly two method calls.

Comment: if you are using the pathlib library do: `p.is_file()` see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44228884/1601580

Answer (score 148):

use `os.path.isdir(path)`

more info here http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html

Comment: If I use this to determine if something is a *file*, what if the thing at `path` is a symbolic link?

Comment: This doesn't appear to work with file descriptors when using process substitution.

Comment: if you are using the pathlib library do: `p.is_file()` see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44228884/1601580

Answer (score 74):

Many of the Python directory functions are in the [`os.path` module](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html).

```
import os
os.path.isdir(d)
```

Comment: if you are using the pathlib library do: `p.is_file()` see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44228884/1601580

Answer (score 22):

An educational example from the [stat](http://docs.python.org/library/stat.html) documentation:

```
import os, sys
from stat import *

def walktree(top, callback):
    '''recursively descend the directory tree rooted at top,
       calling the callback function for each regular file'''

    for f in os.listdir(top):
        pathname = os.path.join(top, f)
        mode = os.stat(pathname)[ST_MODE]
        if S_ISDIR(mode):
            # It's a directory, recurse into it
            walktree(pathname, callback)
        elif S_ISREG(mode):
            # It's a file, call the callback function
            callback(pathname)
        else:
            # Unknown file type, print a message
            print 'Skipping %s' % pathname

def visitfile(file):
    print 'visiting', file

if __name__ == '__main__':
    walktree(sys.argv[1], visitfile)
```

Comment: Not the prettiest solution, but if you've already got a stat structure, this allows you to avoid making an extra system call / disk seek via os.path.isfile or friends.