# How Would You Go Through a Directory and Get the Files From Them With a For Loop?

Tags: python, file, directory, editing

I am trying to get all the files from a directory and edit them, one by one, but I cannot figure out how. I tried looking  at the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19587118/iterating-through-directories-with-python), but the answer wasn't quite what I needed. Here is my code:

```
import os
playeritems = 'PlayerFiles/PlayerItems'
for files in os.walk(playeritems):
    for file in files:
      with open(os.path.join(file), 'r') as t:
        t_reading = t.readlines()
        for i in t_reading:
          #Do what I need to do to the line of code.
```

I am trying to look through each file and change some of the lines in it, but it keeps giving me the error:

> IsADirectory: Is a directory on `with open(os.path.join(file), 'r') as t:`

I got my current code from the question above, so if there are other errors in it, I will fix them as soon as I find them.

Comment: which line is throwing that error? That's where to start looking.

Comment: [Maybe not a dupe but helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/955941/how-to-identify-whether-a-file-is-normal-file-or-directory-using-python). Do `os.path.isfile()` before opening it as a file and `readlines`ing. `os.walk` may be easier as `os.listdir` if you just want the files in a directory.

Comment: replace your loop line with: `for _, _, files in os.walk(...):`

Comment: See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.
`print files` between your two `for` statements will show your first error.  `print` is your debugging friend.  It will also help if you follow the code in the question you cited, instead of changing things you don't *quite* understand ... yet.  `print` will help fix that, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not including the sub-directories possibility or the directories possibility to look for in `playeritems`. My code should look like:

```
for _, __, files in os.walk(playeritems):
    for file in files:
      with open(os.path.join(playeritems, file), 'r') as t:
        #Do stuff to the file
```