# Parsing of multiple XML files in the same directory

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, parsing, xml-parsing

I want to read different XML files to do the parsing later.
My **code** is below, but I got following exception:

> IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: 
>   '.ipynb_checkpoints'

This is my code:

```
from os import listdir
for file in listdir():
    print(file)
    xmlTree = parse(file)
    elemList = []
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to identify whether a file is normal file or directory using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/955941/how-to-identify-whether-a-file-is-normal-file-or-directory-using-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I post the answer if someone else got my error.

```
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if not filename.endswith('.xml'): continue
    fullname = os.path.join(path, filename)
    xmlTree = parse(filename)
```